# Are Global/Nested functions in JavaScript implemented as closures?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an school assignment comparing higher-order function/closure implementation in Swift and JavaScript.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) explicitly mentions global and nested functions in Swift as a special case of closures, but I have been unable to find any similar/conflicting information about their implementation in JavaScript.

A cursory search returned [this blog post](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/30/is-javascripts-global-scope-really-just-a-closure/) which suggests that the global scope in JS is implemented as a closure, but I can't seem to find solid evidence which I would be comfortable including in my report. (Most searches simply return overviews of JS closures/scoping which aren't useful to me.)

If any JS gurus are familiar enough with this implementation I'd really appreciate the information.

Cheers!

Comment: A closure in javascript, is really a function that *returns* an inner function that has access to *free variables*, but the term "closure" is often used somewhat loosely on all sorts of patterns. I don't see how the global scope (in a browser) can be a true closure, as the variables that are defined in it are not free in any way, nothing is returned, and it's in no way similar to a closure. Nested functions aren't neccessarely closures either, only if they return a function that accesses free variables in the scope of the outer wrapper function.

Comment: Are you asking how the global scope works under the hood?

Comment: @AndyRay I'm mostly interested in comparing the higher-order function implementation in Swift/JS; I thought it was interesting that Swift documentation explicitly mentioned a closure-based implementation for global scope (and hence global functions). If JS uses some specialized machinery to drive functions in the global scope an overview of that would be helpful.

Comment: @adeneo - while closure and return value are related, they are independent concepts and either can exist without the other. You can definitely create a closure without any return value (think `setTimeout`)

Comment: Search SO for "are all functions closures".

Comment: @Amit - that's true, the inner function doesn't have to return anything, generally a function inside another function is a closure, as it has access to the free variables in the outer functions scope. However, the statement *"Each and every function creates a closure in JavaScript..."* that is claimed by the answer below, is not correct in my opinion, but I see after a search that opinions vary.

Comment: @adeneo, *your opinion* does not change the fact that closure creation process is identical for every function, and every function creates a closure.

Comment: @AkshayArora - I'm not taking it personally, I really couldn't care less, but in my opinion every function *creates it's own scope*, but not neccessarely a closure, unless there is a function that actually refers to free variables. In other words, the function defined **in the closure** 'remembers' the environment in which it was created, hence one would need a function inside a function that refers to variables in the scope of the outer function for those variables to be enclosed.

Comment: @adeneo 1. I am deleting one of my comment, it lacked maturity. 2. What I am saying is that *formation of a closure* is a side effect of what I wrote below. I do think that the difference between our thoughts is just because of terminology. You say, a function is said to form a closure, when it inherits a non-null `outerLex` object. All I am saying is that every function inherits an `outerLex` object, whether null or not. So, technically, what I am saying is a more generalisation of what you are saying, and closure is formed everytime, although `outerLex` may be null sometimes.

Comment: @adeneo, I cannot match your level of expertise, you have a gold badge in JavaScript, and I am a beginner, honestly. But I think what I am saying is pretty correct and generalised, and taken from the ECMA standard.

Comment: @AkshayArora - Closures are hard to understand, even if they seem so simple, and I'm not sure I've totally understood them myself. High reputation doesn't really mean I know more about closures either, but it's my opinion that a closure is possible because ECMAScript allows inner functions; functions that are inside the function bodies of other functions. That's why you can't have closures in C, for instance, there are no inner functions. Those inner functions are allowed access to all variables and parameters declared within their outer function....

Comment: ...a closure is formed when one of those inner functions is made accessible outside of the function in which it was contained, so that it may be executed after the outer function has returned. At which point it still has access to the local variables, parameters and inner function declarations of its outer function. Those local variables, parameter and function declarations (initially) have the values that they had when the outer function returned and may be interacted with by the inner function.

Comment: Or as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) puts it, *"Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In other words, the function defined **inside** the closure **remembers** the environment in which it was created"*, meaning one would need nested functions, and an inner exposed function, that has access to the enclosed variables of the outer function, to create a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lexical Scoping

---

Dictionary defines lexical as "pertaining to words or vocabulary of a language". Lexical scope of a function in JavaScript is statically defined by the physical placement of the function in the code.

```
var a = "Top of all";

function first(){
 var b = "I am first";
  function second(){
   var c = "I am second";
   }
}
```

This forms a lexical hierarchy:

global --> first --> second

### variableEnvironment [Read 10.4 and 10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Every possible scope in JavaScript has its own execution context. Each execution context has its own variableEnvironment - This is the place where all the variables of that context live. Every invocation of a function establishes and enters a new execution context and hence a new variableEnvironment.

Take Away: **Each variableEnvironment will also inherit the variableEnvironment of its immediate lexical scope**.

I can also frame it in this way: **Each variableEnvironment inherits the variableEnvironment of the context that created it**.

So for the example above, `first` inherits variableEnvironment of global, and `second` inherits the variableEnvironment of `first`.

## How does this inheritence work?

---

During the execution, whenever a new function is called, a new execution context is created, hence a new variableEnvironment is created. This new variableEnvironment has a property called `outerLex`, which holds the variableEnvironment of the lexical scope that created it.

So how does the variableEnvironment for the function `second` in our example look like?

```
{
 c: ... // own variables
 outerLex: {
   b: .. // variables of outer lexical scope
   outerLex: {
      a: .. // global variable
   }

 }
}
```

Does it start to make sense? This also should explain why variables are "shadowed" when they are present with the same name in different scopes.

Also notice that the variables are **prioritized by lexical proximity**.

*I have already explained closures*. All theory you have read elsewhere should start making sense.

The innermost variableEnvironment has an `outerLex` property which *references* the variableEnvironment above it, and thus preventing variables of outer scope from being garbage collected. Garbage collection works by checking how and which elements are referring what elements. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Even if the function `first` has returned and ended execution, function `second` can still validly refer to the variable `b` defined in it, because it has a reference to its variableEnvironment.

## Let's dig deeper (and also answer your question)

---

When a function is created, the variableEnvironment is inherited automatically. 
And we already saw above that inheritence of variableEnvironment creates a function closure.

**So, A closure is formed on function creation and it has nothing to do if the function has returned or not (common myth)**

Also, JavaScript objects work through reference.

**So, outer variables are referred, and not *copied* in the variableEnvironment**

## Answer to your question

---

**Each and every function creates a closure in JavaScript**.
It is a common misunderstanding that only inner functions create closure, which is not the case.

## Functions in global scope also form closures, but their closure is boring, because it only references the global variableEnvironment, which is visible in any case.

Finally, you say you need a document to link for your homework. [This should suffice ;)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

[Edit]: I hate terminology. Whenever the `outerLex` property is empty, some people like to say that a closure is not formed. Meh.

**[Edit 2]: Most of what is written in this article is contrary to what is floating on the web. Kindly read the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) standard to support *any* of your claim.**

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the thorough explanation (and the reference) - this is just what I needed.

Comment: A global variable is only the most trivial example of a closure. Once you understand that you will also understand the true nature of closures: they're just a more generalised form of "global" scope - they're shared scopes.